# How can I find out when a public synonym was last updated

Tags: sql, oracle, synonym

I have access to a public Synonym in an Oracle database but I can't see when the table was updated or if indeed it is being updated - so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your asking for... when the public synonym was last updated, or the table it is pointing to was last updated?

Comment: When the table it was pointing to was last updated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select  scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn)) 
from <your schema.tablename>
```

Note that this only works for inserts or updates, not deletions.

Here are some references about [ora_rowscn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm) and [scn_to_timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions142.htm)

Comment: Be aware that `scn_to_timestamp` is only good for a few days.  Old SCNs will generate `ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1`.